# Streamlit pdf file cannot be opened after downloading with st.download_button

Tags: python, pdf, download, streamlit

I want to download a pdf on button click in my streamlit application.
I am using [`st.download_button`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.download_button), like this:

```
st.download_button(
            label="Download",
            key="download_button",
            on_click=None,  # You can specify a callback function if needed
            file_name="MyDocument.pdf",
            data="MyDocumentSource.pdf",
            help="Click to download.",
        )
```

The pdf file is in the same directory as the python script. And I can open the pdf file as such. However after downloading (which also works), I can not open the pdf file and I get - "file could not be opened due to unsupported datatype".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I  also checked and the type of the downloaded file is pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to first read in the pdf as such:

```
with open("MyDocumentSource.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file:
    document = pdf_file.read()
```

Then the `data` argument needs to be specified as the read in data. Here  `document` and not the path.

```
data=document,
```